# YumUserController not found Yii

Tags: php, yii, yii-components

hi i am running someone Else's code based on `Yii`.I tried to run it but i found the error.
`Fatal error: Class 'YumUserController'` not found in `C:\wamp\www\msl\framework\YiiBase.php on line 204`And also it displays html/php content,can any one please suggest me what the actual issue occurring.I have installed yii in my `/www/yii/`, and in yii folder i put my framework along with the project file in `www/yii/framework,and my project`

Comment: This is User management controller check the code here . https://code.google.com/p/yii-user-management/source/browse/trunk/user/controllers/YumUserController.php?r=451

Comment: even though i have updated this file then also same error occurs

Comment: have you registered the user module in  main.php ?

Comment: i am totally noob for Yii can u please help me with the registration